# How To Name A Element on Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox  x:Name="Name" Style="{StaticResource MainTextBox}" MaxLength="10" Height="35" Width="175"/>
    <TextBlock  Padding="8" FontFamily="{StaticResource BRoyaBold}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}" Text="Code" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name.Text))
{
    searchstring += " And UserName like '%" + Name.Text.Trim() + "%'"
}
```

Name.Text dosent show, like my visual studio not doesn't know what is ".Text" on my TextBox
I Cant Use That's inputs strings
How Can I named My TextBox?

Comment: Because your `TextBox` doesn't have a name assigned to it.

Comment: it dosent know CodeMeli.Text Also

Comment: Name is a name already taken. A window, page, usercontrol already have a string  NameProperty which you reference with Name.  That's what it's telling you with the error frameworkelement.name etc.  Call your control something else. Something that isn't already in use. If that then doesn't work then you need to provide more explanation of where your code is and where your markup is if you still want help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextBox` doesn't have a name assigned to it, so unlike in `WinForms` where controls are automatically given a name if unassigned, `WPF` simply works without a name. So you have to give it a name, like so:

```
<TextBox Name="Name" Style="{StaticResource MainTextBox}" MaxLength="10" Height="35" Width="175"/>
```

Comment: when i move mouse on Name.Text it show me string FrameworkElement.Name(get;set) , and my error is 'string does not contain a definiton for 'text' and no extension method, i removed x:Name to Name but it dosent work again